# php to create an array with value stored in variables

Tags: php, arrays

well, i have 2 variables

```
$variable1 = "123";
$variable2 = "321";
```

both variables are calculated by other methods and may vary due to change of circumstances, now i want to put these values in a single array for displaying, what i want is something like this

```
$array = ($variable1, $variable2)
```

and print like(in IDE)

```
array([0]=>123 [1]=>321)
```

both 123 and 321 are representations of variable values.

i tried compact() function but it gave me something weird, i tried make these two variables an array with only one element and merge them into one array but in fact i have many variables and it's infeasible to do this for every one of them.....please show me how i can do it and explain in detail the mechanism behind it, thank you very much.

Comment: `$newArray = [];$newArray[] =  $variable1;$newArray[] = $variable2;print_r($newArray)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want.
You can use one of examples below :

```
// Define a new array with the values
$array1 = array($variable1, $variable2);
// Or
$array2 = [$variable1, $variable2];

// Debug
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);

// Define an array and add the values next
$array3 = array();
$array3[] = $variable1;
$array3[] = $variable2;

// Debug
print_r($array3);

// Define an array and push the values next
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
$array4 = array();
array_push($array4, $variable1);
array_push($array4, $variable2);

// Debug
print_r($array4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the array function to get the values into one array.

```
$var1 = "123";
$var2 = "321";

$array = array($var1,$var2);
```

var_dump($array); returns:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '123' (length=3)
  1 => string '321' (length=3)
```

Or another example on how you could do it is:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = myFunction(); //myFunction returns a value and by using $array[] you can add the value to the array.
$array[] = myFunction2();

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to put these item in array 
First you have to initialize a variable

```
$newArray = []
```

After that you have to store the value in array which can be done by this

```
$newArray[] = $variable1;
// OR BY
array_push($newArray, $variable1);
```

They both are same it push the data to the end of the array

So your code will be like this

```
$newArray = []
$newArray[] = $variable1;
$newArray[] = $variable2;
```

If you want to do it in loop then do somthing like this

```
$newArray = []
foreach($values as $value){
    $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

If there is a fix value then you can do like this

```
$newArray = [$variable1, $variable2];
//OR BY
$newArray = array($variable1, $variable2);
```

Both are same

And to print the value use

```
print_r($newArray);
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
$variable1 = "123";
$variable2 = "321";

$arr =array();
array_push($arr,$variable1);
array_push($arr,$variable2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.